# JQuery datepicker in partial view not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, datepicker, partial-views, umbraco7, ajax.beginform

I'm using a datapicker in my dialog modal.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

I call datepicker from the main view than load partialview:

```
<script src="/Scripts/dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
        var isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);
        if (isSafari || isChrome) {
            var d = value.split("/");
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date((/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) ? d[1] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[2] : value));
        } else {
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
        }
    };

        $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", minDate: 2 });
    });
</script>

    <div id="modal" title="Requestnow">
    <div id="modal-dialog-content">
        @Html.Partial("MyController/_Request", new RequestModel())
    </div>
</div>
```

In my master template I have all libraries called:

```
<!-- Javascripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<script src="/scripts/fanoe.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

Then after them the partial is inserted at the bottom of the page just before `body` closing tag.

The view renders well and datepicker works on the first rendering.

When I then post back the form which is in modal with ajax, the datepicker stops working. In the source it seems it does not render at all, the text field looses hasDatepicker class etc.

I tried to put the datepicker call inside the partialview and the datepicker renders properly after post back but if I post back it again the partialview replace my parent view and return javascript error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

because obviously all jquery scripts are in the parent view which is not being rendered.

Tried to search for solution cos I saw similar posts but no luck for now.

I'm using Umbraco and the partialview is strongly typed:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<RequestModel>
```

Dialog js:

```
$(function () {

    // Don't allow browser caching of forms
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    var dialog = $('#modal').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        title: $('#modal').attr('title'),
        buttons: {
            "Close": {
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                text: 'Close',
                class: 'ui-icon-close'
            }
        }
    });

    if ($(".btn-get-quote").length > 0) {
        $(".btn-get-quote").button().on("click", function () {
            dialog.dialog("open");
        });
    }

});
```

Partial view content is standard:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Request", "MyController", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "quote-form", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    <div id="quote-form">
        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

        [all form fields in razor]
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StartDate)
            </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: show your javascript code.

Comment: @BG101 I have updated the question with more code